# Delete data from multiple tables in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

I'm working on Spring Boot application, we use PostgreSQL for our DB, in this DB we have multiples schemas, and in each schema we have multiples tables which have multiples relations between them (Many to Many, Many to on, and simple relations), we have also views and matérialized views.
I've been asked to delete all data in a specific schema using a rest API which take the name of the schema as parameter. My question is:
how could I delete all data in all tables of a specific schema, should I use named query in the dao? And how I Can Do that for all tables in the same Time with one query?

My second question: should I delete data in views and matérialized views? Is it similaire to deleting from tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native SQL statement to delete all data in a specified schema.
The statement that deletes all data in all tables from a specified schema for **PostgreSQL** looks like:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE _tablename TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR _tablename IN 
        SELECT tablename
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname = :your_specified_schema
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE public.%I CASCADE;', _tablename);
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

In spring-boot, you can use a JdbcTemplate or a native query to execute this code.

You don't need to delete data from ordinary `views`, but in the case of `materialized views`, you need to refresh them by executing [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html).

Comment: Hi friend thank  you very match for thue answer, actualy i have this schema :